# Tornado: Unpack many layers of Future

Tags: python, function, asynchronous, tornado, future

In tornado 4.3 + python3, if I have many layers of async function, e.g.:

```
@gen.coroutine
def layer_2():
    return(yield async_func())

@gen.coroutine 
def layer_1():
    return(yield layer_2())

@gen.coroutine
def main():
    return(yield layer_1())
```

Since an async function returns a Future (yielding this Future returns its result), to get the returned value of `async_func` in `main`, I have to:

- In each callee, wrap the yielded Future in a return statement
- In each caller, to pass the value up the calling chain, yield the callee and warp the returned value in a return statement again

Is there anyway to avoid this pattern ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct way to call coroutines from coroutines in Tornado. There is no "way to avoid this pattern", indeed this is how coroutines work by design!

For more info, see the [Tornado coroutines guide](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/coroutines.html) or my [Refactoring Tornado Coroutines](https://emptysqua.re/blog/refactoring-tornado-coroutines/).

Comment: yeah I understand that, but isn't this approach ugly (duplicate code) ? One approach I can think of is to keep yielding in `main()` until the returned result is no longer a future.

Comment: This is how coroutines are designed to work. There's no more "duplication" than the fact that normal Python functions all need the "return" keyword already.

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to double check the SO hive mind in case I missed anything. I've marked your answer as correct!